# Command to get Locator of reader account in snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, share

I have a procedure that is having code for share/secure view in snowflake.
for that, I have created a reader account.
Statement for creating reader account

```
CREATE MANAGED ACCOUNT if not exists test_acc admin_name='developer123', admin_password='XYZ123temp', type=reader, COMMENT='';
```

This returns `accountName and loginURL` when created for 1st time otherwise return `test_acc` already existed.

I am looking for a statement/command in snowflake so that I can retrieve Locator/accountName for reader accounts.

Note:- Locator is unique 8 char varchar that gets generated for each reader account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "show managed accounts"? It lists the managed accounts created for your account:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-managed-accounts.html

It's also possible to list specific account(s) using LIKE:

```
show managed accounts like 'GOKHAN_READER';
```